# c-sky family based gx6605 firmware analysis to read data

Tags: firmware-analysis

from past few days i am fiddling with the firmware file of dvb s2 receiver of gx6605s processor.
my preliminary purpose is to ***read the hidden menu password*** for given firmware.(password used to hide-unhide menu)
Dump.bin extraction gives 7 other bin files boot.bin,data.bin,info.bin,kernel.bin,logo.bin,root.bin,table.bin..

Kernel.bin is lzma compressed so using a hex editor i removed the lzma header to search the menu password but could'nt find it may be due to a lay man's approach.I also used binwalk with various commands to further extract the fragments but now clueless what to do next.
I request the group members to help me & guide me in choosing the appropriate approach.
Thank you..

firmware link is shared below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c2SyGaHu5I9P1jRCWKQomAYNQBYbgmg4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried further extracting data.bin file ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QxBfm4lv8Jddr4__1aa0H0QJrbBYjZl0?usp=sharing

Comment: yes i have extracted data.bin using binwalk & got 72 files ,36 files are named with offset numbers,rest 36 have same numbers with zlib extension...dont know what to do further..link for retrieved files is provided above.